# php DomDocument xpath: how can i print the all html content of an element resulted from an xpath query?

Tags: xpath, php-5.3, xpathquery

I'm using DomDocument to query for html elements.
when i use `$obj->textContent` or `$obj->nodeValue` it returns only the texts that include in the element, it does not return the html representation of the object.

which means..
if the object contains

```
<div>test</div>
```

the return value for both tries will be `test`.

how do i fetch the html elements as well?

I know that there are other solutions for this besides domDocument like DomHTMlDocument and others but i'd prefer to work a solution with DomDocument.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried a solution such as http://refactormycode.com/codes/708-innerhtml-of-a-domelement ?